# How to get all opened files with vscode api?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to get all the opened files with vscode API.

For example, my editor opened 001.cpp and 002.cpp, I want to get an array like this, [0] = "001.cpp", [1] = "002.cpp".

I tried to find such an API on https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor, but I only find TextEditor, and it only returned the focused file.

```
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.fileName
```

However, I want an array including all the opened filenames.

Comment: a `TextEditor` only knows of one particular editor, maybe you have better luck in the objects `vscode.workspace` and `vscode.window`

Comment: Already answered here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72774627/836330

Answer (score 2):

Since of April 2022 (1.67) you can now use [Tab API](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_tab-api) to achieve that.

So, in your case you need this:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode'

// Get labels of opened files in all groups
vscode.window.tabGroups.all.flatMap(({ tabs }) => tabs.map(tab => tab.label))
```

To get URI path of each opened tab instead:

```js
vscode.window.tabGroups.all.flatMap(({ tabs }) => tabs.map(tab => {
    if (tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputText || tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputNotebook) {
        return tab.input.uri.path
    }

    if (tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputTextDiff || tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputNotebookDiff) {
        return tab.input.original.path // also can use modified
    }

    // others tabs e.g. Settings or webviews don't have URI
    return null!
}).filter(Boolean))
```

Comment: this wouldn't tell you the file paths, only basenames of the files. how could you get full file paths of each opened tab? or at least the filename of the active tab?

Comment: @VladV Good question! This is undocumented part.
It's easy. See updated answer.