# How do I get all the tabs in a Visual Studio Code window as an array of filenames?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently looking to find the call that will allow me to see all the tabs in a Visual Studio Code editor (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt) being returned back in an array for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const tabArray = vscode.window.tabGroups.all;
```

will return an array of editor groups.  And then within each editor group (or "tabGroup") you can get an array of its tabs with:

```js
const firstGroupOfTabs = tabArray[0].tabs;

const firstTabName = firstGroupOfTabs[0].label;

or 

const firstTabUri = firstGroupOfTabs[0].input.uri;  // gives you a uri if you need the full path - for most, but not all, editor types
```

So you will have to do a loop through the `tabGroups.all`  to get all the fileNames.  One example of doing so:

```js
const tabArray = tabGroupArray.flatMap(group => group.tabs.map(tab => tab.label));
```